# Qt emit signal std::string parameter debug

Tags: string, qt

I'm having an issue when strings are used in Qt signal-slot. For some reason the slot function is not getting the value whenever a signal with string parameter is involved. I've pasted relevant pieces of code below and Qt Creator debug session screenshots for details -

Class HradDelegate:

```
void HradDelegate::OnSsnChanged(std::string param) {
  qDebug() << "HradDelegate::OnSsnChanged() " << param.c_str();
  emit ssnChanged(param);
}
```

As you can notice `param` is `WBMP-FM`, when breakpoint is set after `qDebug()` line,

[image]

Class MainWindow:

```
void MainWindow::init() {
  qRegisterMetaType<std::string>("std::string");
  connect(m_HradDelegate, SIGNAL(ssnChanged(std::string)), this, SLOT(OnSsnChanged(std::string)));
}

void MainWindow::OnSsnChanged(std::string param) {
  qDebug() << "MainWindow::OnSsnChanged() " << param.c_str();
  // extra code removed for clarity
}
```

When breakpoint is set after `qDebug()` line,

[image]

Now the value of `param` is garbage in `MainWindow::OnSsnChanged()` and I get a segmentation fault error.

The project compiles for multi platforms. It works fine on Ubuntu 14.04/16.04 and OS X. When I compile and run on ARM7hf, I see the error above and it happens to all the signals involving `std::string`.

Is there something that I missed?

Thanks.

Comment: must be use QString

Comment: or register std::string

Comment: I did register std::string as shown in the init() method. Also not possible to use QString because HradDelegate::OnSsnChanged() is called from a pure C++ library, which doesn't have access to any Qt specific stuff.

Comment: Are there any secondary threads involved?
If not that should just work without any registering of type, as this could be a "direct connection" and basically be a direct method invocation.

Comment: @eyllanesc it doesn't have to be QString, a signal/slot connection can basically carry any data type. Registering the type is only necessary for "queued connection", which, for example, happen between objecs on different threads.

Comment: This question is off-topic without a complete, self-contained example that reproduces the issue. All I can say is that it works for me, so unless you show a *complete* example that doesn't work, with **enough** information to reproduce the issue, there's no way for anyone to help you. As an aside, methods that accept "large" values should be taking them by const reference, otherwise you force an *expensive* copy of the string. Thus you should have: `void HradDelegate::OnSsnChanged(const std::string &param)`.

Comment: Also note that there's no reason for the compiler to keep the string alive after the `qDebug` call. It can be junk, and that doesn't necessarily indicate the source of the crash.

Comment: Most likely, the standard library you use for your ARM target is buggy, or is binary incompatible with the copy of Qt you're using. Did you build Qt yourself for your target? If not - you should, and that might solve your problems.

Comment: @KubaOber, not possible to to give a complete code since this is part of a very big project. Anyway, thanks for your help. As a test if I copy to a temp string then it works.

Comment: @KubaOber I didn't build Qt libs myself for the target, it came with the target file system. I'll see if I can rebuild Qt.

Answer (score 0):

std::string transform QString and QString transform std::string

```
std::string  name="1234";
QString data = QString::fromStdString(data);
name = data.toStdString()
```

i use 15.04 which is no error,your signal is right and the init before the connet
or u can build a new pro to test, then u can get a result from the compareson between the two.